# Windows Forms "мыльные" формы

Tags: winforms

Возникла такая проблема, даже не проблема, а чисто эстетически не приятная вещь.

Пишу приложение, в программе все выглядит как на рисунке слева, а при запуске как справа.

[image: Изображение]
Заметна некоторая размытость текста, мне это не нравится. Как это можно исправить?

Comment: Понимаю что прошло уже 3 месяца, но тем не менее, каким способом вы отображаете этот текст на форме? Лучше привести фрагмент кода. Если вы уже нашли решение, стоит опубликовать его ответом.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Свою проблему решил при помощи перехода с .Net framework 4.6.1 на 4.7.1. А так же добавлением в app.config строк:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="EnableWindowsFormsHighDpiAutoResizing" value="true"/>
</appSettings>
<System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationConfigurationSection>
  <add key="DpiAwareness" value="PerMonitorV2" />
</System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationConfigurationSection>
```

Comment: Можете поподробней описать, что из текста по ссылке вам помогло и почему? Ответы-ссылки не приветствуются по [ряду причин](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1818/256109)